# Auto-completion from java libs in jython

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, jython

I am using Visual Studio Code as a text editor and I would like to have methods from imported java libs autocompleted while maintaining and implementing my python code.

Furthermore, I have seen some usage of this in some IDEs like PyDev but I'd rather use it in my recent favourite text editor.

Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: pyDev is available for Vs code but the author hasnt implemented support for Jython yet